# Requiring an attribute be defined if and only if a child element is not present for an element in a DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

Consider the following definition from a DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT application (calculator)?>
<!ATTLIST application
        uri CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

My problem is that I want the `uri` attribute to be defined if and only if there is not a `calculator` element.

Is there a way to require this?

Comment: I don't think this is posible even with XSchema, because ambiguity. You show declare both optional and run a second step validation (i.e. XSLT)

Comment: @Alejandro: +1. This sort of stuff is waaaay beyond the abilities of DTD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Alejandro is right. That's not possible with a DTD nor is it possible with [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema). You *can* do this using a co-occurrence constraint with a [RelaxNG](http://www.relaxng.org/) schema or you could use [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) in conjunction with any of those schema languages.

I've resolved issues like this before by using embedded schematron rules with schemas (good discussion of this with XSD on [XFront](http://www.xfront.com/ExtendingSchemas.html) and with RelaxNG on [XML.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/02/11/relaxtron.html)). I've recently been doing something similar in pure RelaxNG but then you have a schema that can only be expressed in that one form.