# XSD - how to specify element structure depending on its attribute value?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xml-validation

I have an XML which I validate by an XSD schema.
inside the XML, I have the element . depending on value of stereotype attribute, I want to have different inner structure for the element; take following two variations:

1)

```
<step stereotype="checkerStep" taskType="tableChecker">
   <tableName>employee</tableName>
</step>
```

2)

```
<step stereotype="branchStep">
   <branchName>whichStep</branchName>
</step>
```

as you can see, if stereotype is "checkerStep", as taskType attribute would be necessary, and a tableName inner element is expected. on the other hand, if stereotype is "branchStep", no attribute should be included and a branchName inner element is expected.

I googled my problem and found some answer which suggests using **choice indicator**, however as it's admitted in the comments under the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801256/condition-based-on-attribute-value-xml-schema) , it's doesn't really address the question; because choice indicator doesn't allow elements with the same name in the same scope!

then, what do I do?

Comment: Among the Stack Overflow questions which address this issue are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517396/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600635/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200365/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634243/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923116/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743510/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956369/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856049/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888101/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592378/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081789/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177678/

Comment: This question addresses a situation very similar to yours and provides two different solutions using XSD 1.1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545674/xml-validation-different-child-tags-based-on-attribute-value/23564251#23564251

Comment: Okay it seems <xs:alternative> and schema 1.1 is my answer, but Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1, doesn't recognize the tag and marks it as an error! what to do about that?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen If I could I'd "favorite" your comment.